# JQuery event listener

Tags: jquery

I've different divboxes and some pictures below them. If I hover the divboxes, they expand from 200px to 400px and the picture below slide.

So I've the function "theRotation" and i call two external function in it like this:

```
function theRotation(){
opendivs(); //this expand the divbox to 400 px
rotatePicture(); //this rotate the picture
}
```

now my problem is, that I want the pictures to slide if the divbox is about 300px NOT before!! (remember it expand from 200px to 400px)

So i need a event listener who tell me when the divbox.width() == 300px 
Is this possible?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call rotatePicture(); in the end of the animation you want inside opendivs() function.

For example if your code is

```
function opendivs() {

divbox.animate({'width':'300px'});

}

function rotatePicture() {

//rotation code

}
```

change opendivs() to

```
{

divbox.animate({'width':'300px'}, rotatePicture);

}
```

theRotation() must now call only opendivs() as rotatePicture() is called from opendivs().

PS
calling rotatePicture() inside opendivs() last will still not work as the function does not wait for the animation to finish.

Comment: that will work y, but I want it to fire the rotatePicture at 300px (it finished at 400px) thats half the way not when the animation is finished.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting it to 300px, call the sliding functions and call the expend to 400px. This should happen seemlessly.

Comment: Could work, but watch out for easing. If the sizing doesn't 'take over where it left off' it won't be smooth. And linear animations often 'feel' less smooth despite being completely linear. If you were math-minded, you could make the calculations for the easing.

Comment: Mhm, can you give me an example of this "call the sliding function and call the expend to 400px" ? Regards and Thx